# How to crossover in a genetic algorithm

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, reinforcement-learning

I just want to ask how the learning process works in a genetic algorithm. How are the values of the weights and biases combined to generate a new generation? I want to make a car go around a track without colliding. What do I do after I initialise two cars with different weights and biases and choose the better one? Do I make a new generation and hope it‘s better than the previous one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is super broad; you have several questions here. If your main concern is crossing over, show what you've tried, and what specifically you need help with. Have you done any research into genetic algorithms?

Comment: Basically I‘ve a got a simple net with neurons, connections, weights and biases. I‘ve got a function which initialises (picks randomly) the weights and biases. As input I‘ve got 5 rays casted at an interval of 45 degrees at the car‘s front and the output is a between -1 and 1 for left and right. I‘ve got a counter which averages the distance to the sorrounding objects and gives feedback to if the gen was good. But how should I teach the network. I apologise if it seems like I barely did research but I am genuinely stuck and there is not good explanation out there.

Comment: It sounds to me that you are describing an artificial neural network and not a genetic algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, this is a really open-ended question.

Let's start with a population of size 50. After evaluating the fitness of each genome in the population, we can sort them in descending order based on how they have scored. From this, I personally like to select the top 3-5 performers to automatically include into the next generation. This can cause [premature convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_convergence) over the long term, since the top performers are theoretically immortal (until they are usurped by a better performing genome), but given we still have 45 more spots to fill, there is room for other combinations to be evaluated.

Next, you're going to need one or more [selection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to pick parents for the 45 offspring. Each algorithm has a different method of picking parents, but most of them are designed to give higher fitness genomes a higher chance of being selected.

With two parents, we're ready for crossover. There are different ways to go about this, but generally, you're going to want to take the more fit of the two parents, iterate through its genes, and if the lesser parent has the same gene, randomly pick between the two (otherwise just copy the more fit gene). Of course, you could copy the entire gene, or you could go deeper and randomize the internal properties of the gene between the two.

After crossing over, then you apply [mutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_(genetic_algorithm)) that randomly modify properties of the offspring's genes. This is vital, as it allows us to (randomly) traverse the search space of the problem you are trying to optimize.

Think of it as combining the fittest genomes of the past generation to try new combinations that have yet to be tested. There are a handful of ways to accomplish this, and the best solution for doing so will require some testing and tweaking.

It appears you are attempting to apply this to a neural network, so I recommend reading [the original NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies (NEAT) paper](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf) if you have yet to do so.